# Loss of quality while adding drawing image on HTML 5 canvas from binary string

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw an image from binary string on to the canvas.

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
     //reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
     reader.onload = function(event){
         var d = $(thisObj.CreateIndoorFormDivControlName).dialog();
         var canvas =document.getElementById('canvasfloorLayout');
        var cxt=canvas.getContext("2d");
         var img=new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            }
            img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+window.btoa(reader.result);
```

I am using the above code but the problem is the image size is getting reduced to the canvas size and quality is dropping like anything. I have been tried with

```
cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.width,img.height);
```

But the image gets cropped. 
I donot want to use reader.readAsDataURL as I need to post the binary to the server. My requirement is to show the full image and draw lines on it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
canvas.width  = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

...if you draw the image at the canvas' native resolution, then when the image gets scaled, it's obviously going to lose quality.

...if you draw the image at the image's native resolution, but the canvas hasn't changed size, then you're going to end up with a partial image, or a partially-filled canvas.

So if you want neither of those, then set the dimensions of the canvas to match the dimensions of the image, and you'll have a canvas-drawn image which matches the resolution of the data-image.

---

**EDIT**

Adding an example of a proxy, between the two.

```
var img = new Image(),
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"), 
    // ......etc


    dimensions = {
        max_height : 800,
        max_width  : 600,
        width  : 800, // this will change
        height : 600, // this will change
        largest_property : function () {
            return this.height > this.width ? "height" : "width";
        },
        read_dimensions : function (img) {
            this.width = img.width;
            this.height = img.height;
            return this;
        },
        scaling_factor : function (original, computed) {
            return computed / original;
        },
        scale_to_fit : function () {
            var x_factor = this.scaling_factor(this.width,  this.max_width),
                y_factor = this.scaling_factor(this.height, this.max_height),

                largest_factor = Math.min(x_factor, y_factor);

            this.width  *= largest_factor;
            this.height *= largest_factor;
        }
    };


dimensions.read_dimensions(img).scale_to_fit();

canvas.width  = dimensions.width;
canvas.height = dimensions.height;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly Then create a "Box" or "Camera" object, which you would set your preferred width to.  There are helper functions which will get you the current screen-size, or the current pixel-dimensions of your canvas' parent, or whatever DOM element you want to match the size of...  From there, get the width and height of the image, the canvas and the screen/DOM element, and decide which one you want to go with. It's simple algebra to translate between them. But if you scale things, you lose quality. Especially at non factor-of-2 ratios.

Comment: @Norguard Could you write some code to elaborate the solution ?

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly have a look.  I'm just saying "which dimension changes the most to get it to fit into the window -- change both of them by that percentage".

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly this is, of course the solution only if the image is bigger than the intended size. If the image is smaller, then you'd want to have a `scale_up_to_fit` function, which uses the smaller factor, rather than the larger one (ie: zooming in until the first dimension hits the edge, instead of zooming in until the second one fits perfectly, and the first one went over).  And you don't have to zoom to fit, you could zoom to cover (keep zooming until the smaller side fits), which uses the exact opposite factor as the "to fit", when scaling up or down...

Comment: base64 encoded image was getting mucked bad, not anymore! thank you!

Comment: Very great solution. This works well for me! (Was trying to draw a large image on a small canvas.)

Comment: @尤川豪 Glad it helped! It's interesting to see the code I was writing 11 years ago. Probably not how I'd structure it today, but it's not like the math has changed any. The mutation here means that each object would only be good for one canvas at a time, so I generally just lean on functions that do pure input/output, these days. Anyway, glad it solved it.